# how to subtract the start Date time from End Date time using python?

Tags: python, xml, datetime

Here My date details

1. start_Date_time = 20200709 15:48:26.603
2. end_Date_time = 20200709 15:58:26.648

Need Elapsed time = end_Date_time - start_Date_time.

Comment: What did you try and what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Elapsedtime = endtime - starttime
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' I got this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the datetime module to achieve this my friend.

```
import datetime

date_time_str_1 = '20200709 15:48:26.603'
date_time_obj_1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str_1, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

date_time_str_2 = '20200709 15:58:26.648'
date_time_obj_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str_2, '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Then:

```
date_time_obj_2 - date_time_obj_1
```

You will get:

```
datetime.timedelta(seconds=600, microseconds=45000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in [Datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module from Python and the example below:

```py
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> # read 
>>> d1 = datetime(2020,7,9,15,48,26,603)
>>> d2 = datetime(2020,7,9,15,58,26,648)
>>>
>>> # calculate difference and print total amount of seconds
>>> diff = d2 - d1
>>> print(diff.total_seconds())
600.000045
>>>
>>> # keep the difference as a timedelta object
>>> diff
datetime.timedelta(0, 600, 45)
>>>
>>> # you can check the calculation
>>> d1 + diff == d2
True
```